# SSRS how to access Shared DataSet values in expression

Tags: reporting-services, dataset, connection-string, shared, sqldatasource

I need to set the connection string somewhere in one place in SSRS project in order to use it in Data Sources across all the reports. As SSRS doesn't support project params it's recommended to create Shared DataSet instead, e. g. HostParam.rds

```
SELECT 'localhost' AS GlobalParameter
```

The question is how to access it further in expression in Data Source connection string

```
="Data Source=" + HostParam.GlobalParameter + ";Initial Catalog=xxx"
```

gives an error 'HostParam' is not declared

Answer (score 2):

You can setup a shared datasource at the project level, this contains just the connection to the database.

You then select this shared datasource when creating datasets (this works for both shared datasets or embedded datasets).

If you change the connection in the shared data source, this is reflected in all the datasets and therefore reports that reference it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution. I've got shared data source with the connection string Data Source=.;Initial Catalog="PAM Cube" then I use this shared data source reference in report data source DataSource1. Both shared Data Source and report DataSource1 are of type Analysis Services. And when the report is deployed on local server it gives error "Cannot create a connection to data source 'DataSource1'. (rsErrorOpeningConnection)
Value cannot be null.".  However, when I use the connection string  Data Source=.;Initial Catalog="PAM Cube" directly in report DataSource1 it works ok

Comment: And all other report Data Sources of type Microsoft SQL Server work ok using Shared Data Sources of the same type. It looks like something is wrong with MS Analysis Services type in combo with Shared Data Source. Please, help!